# Partial Dependence Plots for Linear Mixed-Effects Models?

Tags: mixed-model, importance, partial-dependency-plots

I am currently using R and am trying to figure out a way to use partial dependence plots for mixed-effects models. I have heard that PDP plots are model-agnostic, but I have never heard of any PDP for them. Can such a thing be done?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PDPs would be effectively estimated marginal means plots with linear (mixed effects) models.  Recommend looking into packages like `emmeans`, `ggeffects`, or `effect` to estimate and subsequently visualize the effect of a predictor in a linear mixed model.

Comment: @jluchman Thanks a lot, this is the EXACT answer that I was looking for! If you post this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDPs would be effectively estimated marginal means plots with linear (mixed effects) models. Recommend looking into packages like `emmeans`, `ggeffects`, or `effect` in R to estimate and subsequently visualize the effect of a predictor in a linear mixed model.